# .NET equivalent of SendMessage

Tags: .net, visual-c++

Can anyone help with an example to elaborate about the .NET equivalent of VC++ SendMessage/PostMessage? The SendMessage really helps handling over the messages to windows message pump where execution of these will be automatically handled by Windows. I need the same in .NET.

Comment: Send/PostMessage are platform APIs that can easily be called from .Net via p/invoke...  However you should elaborate on exactly what it is you want to use them with/for so people can suggest possible methods that do not require dipping into the API.

Comment: Control::Invoke() or Dispatcher::Invoke().  Or SynchronizationContext::Send() in a library that might be used with different UI frameworks.  You'll strongly favor BeginInvoke/Post for the same reasons you'll favor PostMessage() in a worker thread.

Comment: @AlexK. We had a simple VC++ application where we used this SendMessage to talk from one class to another using messageId, WPARAM and LPARAM. Based on this message Id, the application would itself route messages between different classes for data (and even data lists) sharing in addition to keep things synchronized using Windows own message pump. We want the same in .NET and not using VC++ anymore.

Comment: @HansPassant, I haven't worked with the options you have suggested, but I'll check.